# Batch automation using metadata

Tags: batch, file-management, mp3

I recently did some archiving for personal purposes on my music library, extracting file name to make a text document echoing it's file name with information. Was thinking of parsing parts of the file name to echo artist or song, but my music library file names aren't all in the same format. So, I was wondering if I can somehow just echo the metadata instead.

Here's my code so far. Any help and/or lead me to the right direction would be very much appreciated.

```
@echo off
for /r %%a in (*.mp3) do (
(
for %%b in ("%%~na") do echo ^Name of file: %%~b
echo ^Artist:
echo ^Song:
echo ^Album:
echo ^Comment:
)>"%%~dpna.txt"
)
```

I would really love it if the comment section of the metadata could be extracted. I've spent the years adding descriptions to albums. Thanks.

P.S. Not an expert in programming. Just did a few research for the things I wanted to achieve.

Comment: Do you want to do it in order to learn something? Otherwise why not look into various available "music library" tools?

Comment: ...such as ffprobe from FFMPEG

Comment: @Seth Yes, I do various crazy things for archiving my files. And I would want the flexibility to do something with my agenda stated above. Any idea how I could call a file's metadata?

Comment: @grawity Thanks for the suggestion. Seems legit; I've read it's documentation. The only problem I face now is, I don't know how I could echo that to the format I want stated above.

Comment: For a start consider not using batch scripts. For what you want to do they can be pretty horrible. Consider using PowerShell with `Get-ChildItem` and run ffmpeg or another utility to get the meta data as text. Afterwards you can just edit that data like you need to.

Comment: @Seth. Thank you for you're suggestion. How could I achieve that? I'm not that familiar working on powershell, any way I could integrate it into a batch? Beacause having read the documentation for ffprobe. I've come up with a solution to retrieve the necessary details. But I don't know how to echo it in a batch script. Here's my code so far `ffprobe -v error -show_entries format_tags=title,artist,comment -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 input.mp4`

Comment: Well it depends on what you want to do. The same applies to PowerShell and Batch in this case. You could either run the command three times and just let it output its information for one option at a time or you would need to edit the output in some way. It is likely that you want to save the output to a variable in order to output it after running the program at some later time.

Comment: @Seth Having it output three different results would be wonderful but having it run three times wouldn't be ideal, like what you've mentioned. I'll find a work around. My question now is. How can I echo the result or execute that command in a batch script with my format above? Assuming I just want 1 of the three from title, artist, and comment value.